# How to remove from a list that depends on another list in lamba expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Now I have a **ListA** and **ListB**.

**ListA** will have list of bjects with type **customTypeA** 
while **ListB** will have list of bjects with type **customTypeB**

**customTypeA** will have two field **AiD** and **BiD**
**customTypeB** is `ICollection` which will have two field **BiD** and **Status**

May I know how to construct a lambda expression that remove `item` in **ListA** if `item` in **ListB** having **Status**==2 and both `item` are having the same **BiD**?

Similar to below:

```
foreach(var item in ListB)
{
    if (item.Status == 2)
    {
        ListA.RemoveAll(x=>x.BiD == item.BiD);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way that doesn't involve creating new lists would be:

```
ListA.RemoveAll(a => ListB.Any(b => a.BiD == b.BiD && b.Status == 2));
```

In words this means that you remove an element of `ListA` if there is an element in `ListB` which has the same `BiD` and with `Status` equal to 2.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack information. My `ListB` is ICollection and hence there's no `Exists` method for it

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep No problem, just use the `Any` LINQ method then.